# checking a file if it exist or not exist (not working)

Tags: android

I am trying to check the mp3 file located to my raw folder under my res. my mp3 file is exist but my code gives me a false return.

```
String filename = "android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/w";

 Toast.makeText(ViewPager.this, mp3check(filename)+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

checking the mp3 file

```
 public boolean mp3check(String _filename) {
        return new File(_filename).exists();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't think you can treat a raw resource as a regular file.
2. Since it is a resource, there is no need to check if it exists.
3. You can open it using the resource ID.

For example, if your file is named, mysong.mp3, you can open it like this:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mysong);
```

or

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.mysong);
```

You can use the AssetFileDescriptor to play it with a MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    String filename = "android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/w";
    String newFilePath = "new file path";  // ExternalStorageDirectory path
    final Path destination = Paths.get(newFilePath );
    try (
        final InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.w);
    ) {
        Files.copy(in, destination);
    }

Toast.makeText(ViewPager.this, mp3check(filename)+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    public boolean mp3check(String _newFilePath) {
            return new File(_newFilePath).exists();
        }
```

Comment: I am using API 14 but this line ` final Path destination = Paths.get(newFilePath );` required API 26.